# SSAS - Dimension Browser Shows Different Attributes

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimensional-modeling

I have a table in the data source view with UserID (PK), Department, UserName (and other irrelevant attributes).

I create a dimension. I select UserID as PK. I select Department as attribute.
So, now I have a dimension table with attributes: UserID, Department.

I create a hierarchy with Department->UserID.

I go to the browser, click All and then it starts showing me values from another columnn that isn't Department. If I expand further down into the UserID level, it shows me the values from UserName instead of UserID.

What the heck is going on here? It is showing me values from an attribute that I did not even include in my dimension. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check attribute relationship view? However you create the dimension and the hierarchy it can be mixed up in attribute relationships so you will have to set the drill logic manually.

Comment: There is only one attribute relationship: UserID -> Department